# Proper shadow drop on rotation

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to create a rotatable triangle that will always cast a shadow on its base. So far I was able to create the code for making and rotating the triangle but the shadow part is problematic. Here is my minimal code example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectMain
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "white"

        Canvas
        {
            anchors.fill: parent

            // set properties with default values
            property real hFactor: 1    // height factor
            property real trbase: 200
            property color strokeColor: "black"
            property color fillColor: "yellow"
            property int lineWidth: 1
            property real alpha: 1
            property real rotAngle: 0
            property real parentWidth: parent.width; // try
            property real parentHeight: parent.height;

            onStrokeColorChanged: requestPaint();
            onFillColorChanged: requestPaint();
            onLineWidthChanged: requestPaint();

            onPaint:
            {
                hFactor = Math.abs(hFactor)

                var ctx = getContext("2d") // get context to draw with
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // remove what is painted so far
                ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
                ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor
                ctx.fillStyle = fillColor
                ctx.globalAlpha = alpha

                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.translate(parentWidth / 2, parentHeight / 2);
                ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotAngle);
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

                // drawing part, first calculate height using Pythagoras equation
                var trheight = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(trbase, 2) - Math.pow(trbase / 2, 2));
                trheight = trheight * hFactor;
                var hfBase = trbase * hFactor;
                ctx.lineTo(hfBase / -2, trheight); // left arm
                ctx.lineTo(hfBase / 2, trheight); // right arm

                ctx.closePath(); // base drawn automatically
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
            }

            DropShadow
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                horizontalOffset: 0
                verticalOffset: 3
                radius: 3
                samples: 7
                color: "#80000000"
                source: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing the following problems:

The parser gives me some errors about `ShaderEffectSource`, that `recursive` property has to be set, but I dont know whos property is that.

```
Starting M:\bitbucket\qtworkspace\build-mwe-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\mwe.exe...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
ShaderEffectSource: 'recursive' must be set to true when rendering recursively.
ShaderEffectSource: 'recursive' must be set to true when rendering recursively.
ShaderEffectSource: 'recursive' must be set to true when rendering recursively.
ShaderEffectSource: 'recursive' must be set to true when rendering recursively.
QObject::disconnect: No such signal QObject::screenChanged(QScreen*) in items\qquickscreen.cpp:476
M:/bitbucket/qtworkspace/build-mwe-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/mwe.exe exited with code 0
```

Somewhere in the web I have found a bug report that DropShadow property `source` cannot accept `parent` but since Canvas cannot be assigned with `id`, I am not sure how to do it. Other than this, the shadow renders correctly for `rotAngle` at 0 degrees:

[image]

It doesn't rotate correctly after adding some angle, for example 45 degrees:

[image]

It seems to me that the shadow is not being rotated together with the polygon. Can this be adjusted? The last thing is: How to hide shadow behind the polygon? At the moment its interfering with it.

I am not sure either the parser error is connected or not, that's why I have added it together here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since Canvas cannot be assigned with id

Why `Canvas` can't be assigned with `id`?

The following code won't have that warning.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectMain
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "white"

        Canvas
        {
            id: canvas
            anchors.fill: parent

            // set properties with default values
            property real hFactor: 1    // height factor
            property real trbase: 200
            property color strokeColor: "black"
            property color fillColor: "yellow"
            property int lineWidth: 1
            property real alpha: 1
            property real rotAngle: 0
            property real parentWidth: parent.width; // try
            property real parentHeight: parent.height;

            onStrokeColorChanged: requestPaint();
            onFillColorChanged: requestPaint();
            onLineWidthChanged: requestPaint();

            onPaint:
            {
                hFactor = Math.abs(hFactor)

                var ctx = getContext("2d") // get context to draw with
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // remove what is painted so far
                ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
                ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor
                ctx.fillStyle = fillColor
                ctx.globalAlpha = alpha

                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.translate(parentWidth / 2, parentHeight / 2);
                ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotAngle);
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

                // drawing part, first calculate height using Pythagoras equation
                var trheight = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(trbase, 2) - Math.pow(trbase / 2, 2));
                trheight = trheight * hFactor;
                var hfBase = trbase * hFactor;
                ctx.lineTo(hfBase / -2, trheight); // left arm
                ctx.lineTo(hfBase / 2, trheight); // right arm

                ctx.closePath(); // base drawn automatically
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
            }
        }

        DropShadow
        {
            anchors.fill: canvas
            horizontalOffset: 0
            verticalOffset: 3
            radius: 3
            samples: 7
            color: "#80000000"
            source: canvas
        }
    }
}
```

**About the warning:**

I believe that should not consider as a BUG. `DropShadow` is an `Item`, so if you nest with its parent, it will do like render a shadow on the shadow.

**Why didn't the shadow rotated?**

Because you are rotating the contents of `Canvas`.
Even rotate the polygon, these properties won't change. Always drop the shadow vertically.

```
horizontalOffset: 0
verticalOffset: 3
```

**Rotate both:**

[image]

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    rotation: 30
    Canvas
    {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent

        // set properties with default values
        property real hFactor: 1    // height factor
        property real trbase: 200
        property color strokeColor: "black"
        property color fillColor: "yellow"
        property int lineWidth: 1
        property real alpha: 1
        property real parentWidth: parent.width; // try
        property real parentHeight: parent.height;

        onStrokeColorChanged: requestPaint();
        onFillColorChanged: requestPaint();
        onLineWidthChanged: requestPaint();

        onPaint:
        {
            hFactor = Math.abs(hFactor)

            var ctx = getContext("2d") // get context to draw with
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // remove what is painted so far
            ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
            ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor
            ctx.fillStyle = fillColor
            ctx.globalAlpha = alpha

            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.translate(parentWidth / 2, parentHeight / 2);
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

            // drawing part, first calculate height using Pythagoras equation
            var trheight = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(trbase, 2) - Math.pow(trbase / 2, 2));
            trheight = trheight * hFactor;
            var hfBase = trbase * hFactor;
            ctx.lineTo(hfBase / -2, trheight); // left arm
            ctx.lineTo(hfBase / 2, trheight); // right arm

            ctx.closePath(); // base drawn automatically
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }

    DropShadow
    {
        anchors.fill: canvas
        horizontalOffset: 0
        verticalOffset: 3
        radius: 3
        samples: 7
        color: "#80000000"
        source: canvas
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. Only 1 note: Since the parent item has the property `rotation: 30` set, the line `ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotAngle);` inside `Canvas` has to be removed, as this creates double rotation.

Comment: @Bremen Thanks for helping improve the answer, I removed the unused rotate part.